# Get session data in AJAX loaded page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

On my website I start a session at the top of the page. Later in the page I have included the navigation bar, this is the complete file (`nav.php`):

```
<div class="inner">
<ul id="nav" class="menu">
    <li class="first"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Brugklas</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="child"><a href="#">123</a></li>
            <li class="child"><a href="#">456</a></li>
            <li class="child"><a href="#">789</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">I&rsquo;m here!</a>
                       <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">I&rsquo;m here!</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Klas 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">T&amp;O</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Algemeen</a></li>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
        echo '<li><a href="#">Portal</a></li>';
        echo '<li class="last"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="logout();">Logout</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li class="last"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showLoginScreen();">Login</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Now this works fine, until I want to login. (completely done in jQuery, AJAX-style) As soon as I login successfully. I reload the navigation bar (via AJAX), since it needs to change with updated information (logout link and portal link.) That does not work. As soon as I add `session_start();` at the top of `nav.php` it works, but I get the PHP error that a session already has been started.

I can resolve this by not showing the error. This is done with `@session_start();` but in my eyes, the code is still bad. How can I resolve my issue without the `@` in front of `session_start();`

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this at the top of `nav.php`

`if (!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}`

the problem occurs when you load the page at the beginning.
you start the session and you include the `nav.php` where you start the session once again.

if you load the page for the second time the page is independent of the parent and the session can be started again.